# SQL Server with left join/having sum/group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by, outer-join, having

Table B holds planned values. Table M hold actual values. I need to find all rows in table B where either there is no actual values (ie. joined) row in table M, or where joined rows have different total actual value rows. I am trying a combination of an outer join and having sum ... group by to achieve this, but it isn't working because the 'orphans' in table B are not being returned.

My query is:-

```
 SELECT B.Id, B.Date, b.Ref,SUM(M.Actual_Volume), SUM(B.Planned_Volume),
 SUM(M.Actual_Value),SUM(B.Planned_Value)
 FROM
 TableB B
 left JOIN TableM M on M.Id = B.Id 
 inner JOIN TableX on TableX.FieldX = B.FieldX 
 WHERE TableX.FieldY = (SELECT T.FieldY from TableX T where T.FieldX = 408344)
 AND TableX.FieldZ = (SELECT T1.FieldZ from TableX T1 where T1.FieldX = 408344)
 group by B.Id, B.Date, B.Ref
 having SUM(M.Actual_Volume) <> SUM(B.Planned_Volume)
 OR SUM(M.Actual_Value) <> SUM(B.Planned_Value)
 order by b.Id
```

If I use = instead of <> to compare the actuals and planned I get rows that join, but I need the rows where the actuals don't equal the planned, or where there is a planned but not an actual.

Thanks!

```
 Table B
 Id planned_vol planned val
 19 2           350
 28 1           100
 53 3           650
 61 1           50

 Table M
 M.Id B.Id actual_vol actual_val
 58   19   2          350
 65   28   1          100
 66   53   1          150
```

So the query should return,

```
 B.Id 
 53 (because planned_vol <> actual_vol and planned_val <> actual_val)
 61 (because B.Id 61 is not in table M)
```

hth!

Comment: Can you please show some sample data for rows that you want returned (for both reasons) and at least one row that you don't want returned.

Comment: Quick fix would be to add `SUM(M.Actual_Volume) is null or SUM(M.Actual_Value) is null` to having clause, but I think that you are trying to sum both sides of n:m relationship. This will end in data duplication. Could you post more info on your schema and relationship between M and B?

Comment: Yes, tableB to TableM is m:m because the defining table is TableX

Comment: I think your `WHERE` clause could be replaced with this join: `INNER JOIN TableX T ON TableX.FieldY = T.FieldY AND TableX.FieldZ = T.FieldZ AND T.FieldX = 408344` (or `T.FieldX = 408344` could be moved to `WHERE`).

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but I think you need to move the having requirements into the left outer join requirements. Using CTEs (i.e. you need to be using SQL Server 2005 or later for this to work) is one way to do it.

Your having clause is forcing SQL Server to treat the B-M join as an inner join. There may be an alternative approach that does not use CTEs which checks for NULLs in all the right places. But I prefer the divide-and-conquer approach.

```
WITH
[BAlt] AS
(
    SELECT
        [B].[Id],
        [B].[Date],
        [B].[Ref],
        SUM([B].[Planned_Volume]) AS [Planned_Volume],
        SUM([B].[Planned_Value]) AS [Planned_Value],
    FROM [TableB] AS [B]
        INNER JOIN [TableX] AS [X1] ON [X1].[FieldX] = [B].[FieldX]
            AND [X1].[FieldY] =
            (
                SELECT
                    [X2].[FieldY]
                FROM [TableX] AS [X2]
                WHERE [X2].[FieldX] = 408344
            )
            AND [X1].[FieldZ] =
            (
                SELECT
                    [X3].[FieldZ]
                FROM [TableX] AS [X2]
                WHERE [X3].[FieldX] = 408344
            )
    GROUP BY
        [B].[Id],
        [B].[Date],
        [B].[Ref]
),
[MAlt] AS
(
    SELECT
        [M].[Id],
        SUM([M].[Actual_Volume]) AS [Actual_Volume],
        SUM([M].[Actual_Value]) AS [Actual_Value]
    FROM [M]
    GROUP BY
        [M].[Id]
)
SELECT
    [BAlt].[Id],
    [BAlt].[Date],
    [BAlt].[Ref],
    [BAlt].[Planned_Volume],
    [BAlt].[Planned_Value],
    [MAlt].[Actual_Volume],
    [MAlt].[Actual_Value]
FROM [BAlt]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [MAlt] ON [MAlt].[Id] = [BAlt].[Id]
        AND
        (
            [MAlt].[Actual_Volume] <> [BAlt].[Planned_Volume]
                OR [MAlt].[Actual_Value] <> [BAlt].[Planned_Value]
        )
ORDER BY
    [BAlt].[Id]
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2005 9.00.1399.06, so I will give this a go

Comment: Daniel, trying this way, the right sets are being selected AS SELECT clauses, but for some reason the final SELECT is not joining correctly and is returning NULLs for the Actual_Volume & Actual_Value fields. Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: @epx `Actual_Volume` and `Actual_Value` will be null in the cases where an ID exists in `B` but not in `M`. If you want a default value, e.g. zero, use `ISNULL([MAlt].[Actual_Volume], 0)` and equivalent for `Actual_Value` in the final select clause.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see a problem:

```
    create table b
    (    B_id int
        ,PlannedVolume int
        ,PlannedValue int
    )

    create table M
    (    M_id int
        ,B_id int
        ,ActualVolume int
        ,ActualValue int
    )

    insert b (b_id, PlannedVolume, PlannedValue)
    values  (19, 2, 350),
        (28, 1, 100),
        (53, 3, 650),
        (61, 1, 50)

    insert m (m_id, b_id, ActualVolume, ActualValue)
    values  (58, 19, 2, 350),
        (65, 28, 1, 100),
        (66, 53, 1, 150),
        (67, 53, 1, 100)

   select b.b_id
   from b
     left join
     (  select b_id
            ,sum(ActualVolume) as ActualVolume
            ,sum(ActualValue) as ActualValue
        from m 
        group by b_id
     )   m       
     on  m.b_id = b.b_id
   where 
     m.b_id is null
     or
     (m.ActualValue <> b.PlannedValue and m.ActualVolume <> b.PlannedVolume)
```

Comment: the trouble is it isnt 1:1 between b and m, so in m you could also have the row 67,53,1,100. So now for b_id 53 we now have an outstanding planned_volume of 1 and an outstanding planned_value of 400, which is why I was trying GROUP BY ... HAVING SUM, but it isn't there yet :-(